# Посоветуйте библиотеку для реализации генплана

Tags: javascript, php, map, marker

Ищу решение для реализации генплана такого типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- фоновая картинка (карта местности)
- визуальный редактор для размещения меток (кликом/перетаскиванием)
- сохранение меток в БД или файл с возможностью будущего редактирования
- чтобы работало с 200-300 метками без тормозов

опционально хотелось бы:

- возможность просто добавлять свои метки (цвета/форму/содержание)
- всплывающее окно с моим содержанием при клике на метку (для каждой метки своё)
- масштабирование (хотя бы вся карта целиком и увеличенная область)
- работа на мобильных
- метки в форме области (по форме участка)

На чистом JS/CSS это можно сделать, но очень долго. А готовые решения я нашёл только для карт (типа google/yandex), или модули для CMS. А мне хотелось бы простую библиотеку, которую я мог бы интегрировать в свой php сайт.

Comment: https://d3js.org/ d3js! Будет не лишним изучить, для работы с данными очень выручит

Comment: @МихаилКамахин спасибо, посмотрел. А в нём есть возможность сделать визуальный редактор для меток? В документации что-то не нашёл примера...

Comment: Не знаю. d3js самая популярная библиотека, которая помогает работать с визуализацией данных. Я думаю это не так сложно написать код, чтобы править метки

Comment: Еще есть и корпоративные решения https://www.mapbox.com/industries/consumer
https://www.mapbox.com/atlas/

Comment: @МихаилКамахин там на Эл-ты можно тот же on click вешать и делать что угодно на всё той же js